# How to keep track of all my posts on internet forums to which I am a subscriber

Tags: internet, forum

I subscribe and use several forums(as I have varied interests) to read, answer and start new posts. It's quite a pain to keep track of all of them when you post 10-20 posts daily on various forums.

Is there a way, a software or any tip or trick which can help me make my forums management easier.

I Googled for any such software but was disappointed to not find any.

Comment: I use lastpass for the username and passwords on various forums.  Not sure if you are looking for a solution that can track your activities or just for keeping track of the logins.

Comment: @dkjain, you’ll have to be more specific on your needs and what you mean by “management”. Are you talking about login data? update/response notifications? profile information/syncing? statistics? …?

Comment: Most forums I'm familiar with have a link to all posts and/or threads started by a given user on the user's profile page.

Comment: yes there are links to my posts in control panel of the forum but as i said it becomes a hassle to keep track of all your posts, may be you forget to check back, comment on your posts etc. I am looking for solution that can keep track of my activities, ability to categorize my old-new forums posts under user defined heads such as technology,windows7 etc. May be also manage my login info for various forums. It becomes much more easy when there a central place to manage your posts.

Comment: Use http://en.gravatar.com/ 
Your Gravatar is an image that follows you from site to site appearing beside your name when you do things like comment or post on a blog. Avatars help identify your posts on blogs and web forums, so why not on any site?

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I have found. http://www.webforumreader.com/ I've recently started looking for similar software.